# Let hover on vote arrow explain vote lock

Tags: discussion, voting, change-vote

### Current behavior

When you hover over the arrow after you already voted over 5 minutes ago, it explains that you can "click again to undo":

[image: Hover over vote arrow]

However when you click on it, you get the vote lock error:

[image: Click on vote arrow]

### Expected behavior

Let the hover message display the current error message since you can't actually "click again to undo". Possibly explain that the undo window is 5 minutes.

Comment: That would not be reliable. The user may have loaded the page before the 5 minute period expired, in which case the HTML source would not have that hover message. And the "x minutes ago" part of the message would be incorrect for the same reason.

Comment: There's plenty of javascript to take care of that.

Comment: Seems like a very minor issue to add "plenty of JavaScript" for :-)